# Function returning same value for different arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return-value

I am very new to Python (and using Python 3). Apologies---I know I must be making a very basic mistake.

Here is the structure of the mistake and then I'll give an example: I wrote a function `func(x)`.  To test that it does the "right" things, I plugged in value `x1`, i.e. `print(func(x1))`. The output was `y1` which was correct. Then I tried `print(func(x2))`. That again gave me `y1` and not the correct `y2`.  And similarly with other values of `x`. At first I thought it was a mistake with that specific function, but then I had similar issues with other functions.  Am I making a mistake common to all the functions?

Below is one example; I've tried this (and other functions) with several different variations and still had the problem. I can give other examples, if that would help.

```
def num_to_day(x):
   if 0:
      return "Sunday"
   elif 1:
      return "Monday"
   elif 2:
      return "Tuesday"
   elif 3:
      return "Wednesday"
   elif 4:
      return "Thursday"
   elif 5:
      return "Friday"
   elif 6:
      return "Saturday"
   else:
      return "Not Valid"
print(num_to_day(5))
```

Comment: You have to test the condition in you `if`, like this `if x == 0: .. elif x == 1 ..`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your `if` statements, you need to specify *x equals* each number--for example, `if x == 0:`.

Currently, you're testing the truth value of a number itself, with no relation to what `x` you have specified.  To see this, try:

```
if 1:
    print('Monday')
Monday
```

You might find it useful to know that in Python, `0` evaluates to False while other integers return `True`:

```
print([bool(num) for num in range(7)])
[False, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

`bool` tests the truth value of its argument.

Lastly, one alternative of many would be to lookup your weekday from a dict.  `.get` allows you to specify a value that gets returned if an error is thrown.

```
def num_to_day(x):
    days =  {
        0 : 'Sunday',
        1 : 'Monday',
        2 : 'Tuesday',
        3 : 'Wednesday',
        4 : 'Thursday',
        5 : 'Friday',
        6 : 'Saturday'
        }
    return days.get(x, 'Not Valid')

num_to_day(0)
Out[54]: 'Sunday'

num_to_day(10)
Out[55]: 'Not Valid'
```

Comment: That worked!  Thanks! (It won't let me accept the answer for 12 minutes)

Comment: You also might want to use lists for this comparison.
ex. `['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'][day_num]`

Comment: yes, i had tried various version ... but i thought the posted one was easiest to figure out the mistake i was making... i knew it must be basic...

Answer (score 2):

You're not using your argument inside your function at all.

```
def num_to_day(x):
   if x == 0: # <-- Now x gets evaluated
      return "Sunday"
   elif x == 1:
      return "Monday"
   elif x == 2:
      return "Tuesday"
   elif x == 3:
      return "Wednesday"
   elif x == 4:
      return "Thursday"
   elif x == 5:
      return "Friday"
   elif x == 6:
      return "Saturday"
   else:
      return "Not Valid"
print(num_to_day(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an argument to your function and then **not** using it at all. To make if work, you must actually compare `x` to all those numbers, simple `if 0:` is equivalent to `if False:`, not to `if x == 0:`.

And anyway, this cascade of `elif`s is a prime example of how **not** to code. A much better solution would be to use a list or a dictionary:

```
def num_to_day(x):
    days_of_week = [ "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" ]
    return days_of_week[x]
```